# Why my visted link code is not working

Tags: html

I would be grateful if anyone could tell me why the visited-link part of the code below is not working:(The hover color does does work, but there is no change in color after the link has been visited).

Thanks very much,
Jan

```
a {
color: #5fade5;
text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
color: #2d71a4;
}

a:visited
{
color: #096782;
}
/*
```

Comment: some browsers disable this feature for privacy reasons, it's not 100% reliable

Comment: please edit your question and add html link code too

Comment: @MightyPork — I've never seen a browser do that. Most will disable the ability of JavaScript to the `:visited` color using `getComputedStyle` for privacy reasons, but they don't tend to disable `:hover` support for color.

Answer (score 0):

If a link is visited **and** hovered, then all three of the selectors will match the element.

The `a:hover` and `a:visited` selectors have equal specificity, so the rules in the last one overwrite matching properties in the earlier one.

Move the `:hover` rule so it appears after the `:visited` rule so that the `:hover` rules overwrite the `:visited` rules instead of the other way around.

You can learn about [the cascade](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascade) in the CSS spec.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to "why the visited-link part of the code below is not working", actually it is. However:

a) your colours are all very similar, and the hover and visited ones are almost indistinguishable in short pieces of text.

b) as Quentin says, you have the visited and hover rules in the wrong order, so you will see the hover colour once, but never again as the visited one overrules it.

c) finally, don't forget that, once you have clicked the link, it will always keep that colour (except on hover) and never return to the fresh un-visited colour, even after a page refresh, as your browser remembers that you have visited it. To see the original colour again, change the link target url each time you test it.

So all of these points together are probably confusing the issue. To test it out, try giving the three rules very different colours, eg blue, red, and gray (and re-order the hover/visited rules), just so you can see what's happening more clearly. I hope this identifies the problem you are having.

Also you should add a focus rule (with same colour as the hover one, and immediately after it), so that keyboard users can see which link they are on.

Comment: Hi, thanks to everyone for your help. I have made the change you all suggest but am still having trouble getting the visited link to display properly. On a desktop, it does not display at all. On a tablet (ipad), the visit link turns to the color of the hover link -- but only stays that way until the next link is clicked, at which point it reverts to its original color. Perhaps it's relevant that this is a Weebly template that I am trying to edit. Here is the latest version of the code that I have tried:

Comment: Ok, here is the code:-------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

ul, ol, li, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, pre, form, body, html, p, blockquote, fieldset, input {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

a img {
 border: 0;
}

a:link {
 color: #092a82;
 text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
    color: #096782;
}

a:hover {
 color: #2d71a4;
}

Answer (score -1):

I believe the issue is that you should have `a:link {}` instead of just `a {}`, also take away the `/*` unless you are having a comment and make sure you close it with another `*/` . Your CSS should look something like this:

```
a:link {
color: #5fade5;
text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
color: #2d71a4;
}

a:visited {
color: #096782;
}
```

Comment: The only thing adding `:link` would do would be to stop the `text-decoration` rule from applying to visited links and anchors which weren't links at all. Having an open comment at the end of a CSS file does no harm.

Comment: Thanks to everyone. It turns out that the order is part of the problem, but there is still one remaining issue. The code that I am trying to adjust is a Weebly template, and I am far from expert-level getting into html.css. I have changed the order, but now there are two problems: 1) The visited link is still not showing on a desktop. 2) On a tablet, it shows but only once. I am pasting a larger section of the code as it now exists: